# Is there a way to know if a relationships exist between 2 entities in core data?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

Is there a way to know if a relationships exist between 2 entities in core data?

I don't mean to know if the relationships return a nil value or an actual object, but if it the relationship does exist in the model and I can perform such selector.

I can't use `respondsToSelector:` because in some NSManagedObject subclass I've overridden the relationship methods for other reasons.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the api of [`NSRelationshipDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSRelationshipDescription_Class/NSRelationshipDescription.html). You can query your `NSManagedObjectModel` for every detail of the entities, attributes and relationships.